# MySQLWorkbench quit unexpectedly on macOS Big Sur 11.1

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have tried to re-install, but still cant open MySQLWorkbench. This is the error I get:

```
Process:               MySQLWorkbench [3352]
Path:                  /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench
Identifier:            com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench
Version:               8.0.23.CE (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           MySQLWorkbench [3352]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-01-19 08:21:33.443 -0500
OS Version:            macOS 11.1 (20C69)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     5.1 (18P3030)
Anonymous UUID:        36AA1C89-5799-157D-2CB8-D2DF0B83C543

Sleep/Wake UUID:       23957CD2-4BD4-40B9-94C3-244059218D75

Time Awake Since Boot: 7700 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Abort trap: 6
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x6

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
```

Comment: it is a referenced bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102284

Comment: @Shadow I dont know how to do that, pretty new at this. How can i go about this?

Comment: bugs.mysql.com - this is where you can raise a bug report - but  it is possible that there already is one.

Comment: For me is not working the last release 8.0.23, but works ok 8.0.22 in Big Sur

Comment: It seems that every other release of the workbench has problems on Mac. Any idea why their quality is so poor on macos? (I assume it must be better on Windows)

Comment: latest version of workbench has a bug with bixer, try for version:8.0.21, that will work on your mac https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

Answer (score 89):

the latest version of workbench has a bug, try https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/ for `version:8.0.21`, that will work on your mac

Comment: I can confirm that version 8.0.21 works. Versions 8.0.22 & 8.0.23 don't work.

Comment: How do you install versions prior to 8.0.23 on Mac? If I download and install an older version from the archives link above, say 8.0.21, it seems to automatically update to 8.0.23.

Comment: I can also confirm that version 8.0.22 does not work on Catalina, but version 8.0.21 works.

Comment: 8.0.22 works for me on Catalina (10.15.7), but 8.0.23 does not.

Answer (score 25):

Version 8.0.22 works on macOS Big Sur 11.1

Version 8.0.23 did not not work on my macOS Big Sur 11.1

Comment: i have exactly the same problem

Comment: Voted! 
- 8.0.22 works fine on Big Sur 11.1
- 8.0.23 doesn't work
- 8.0.24 doesn't support Big Sur 11.1.

Answer (score 20):

### June 2023 Update- works perfectly

I had the same issue (running version 8.0.33 on an M1 MacBook Air) as of January 2023. I just installed version 8.0.31 from MySQL Workbench archives, and it works.

Download link:
https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/p/8/file/mysql-workbench-community-8.0.31-macos-x86_64.dmg

Comment: Version 8.0.32 crashed on my M2 MacBook Air, but upgrading to 8.0.34 solved it.

Answer (score 8):

I just installed  workbench 8.0.22 on MacOs big sur 11.2. It works well. however, it doesn't work for workbench 8.0.23.

Answer (score 6):

`8.0.27` works for MacOs Monterey. I got from [workbench](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/)

Comment: This also works fine for me using MacOs Monterey

Answer (score 5):

check the error you got when you run this command:

```
/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench
```

Installing python 3.7 will Solve the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

you should try workbench 8.0.19...
https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/p/8/file/mysql-workbench-community-8.0.19-macos-x86_64.dmg
works fine in MacOS BigSur

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench 8.0.29 works for MacOs Monterrey too. I got it from
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Answer (score 0):

If Workbench launches okay, but quits unexpectedly when you attempt to connect to a database, the problem may be a corrupted Snippets file. Try moving the file (located at ~{user ID}/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench/snippets/User Snippets.txt ) to the Desktop or some other location, and starting Workbench again.