# MySQL Workbench crashes on mac os (fresh install)

Tags: mysql-workbench

I installed mySQL workbench and I can't open it, it crashes right away.
SQL is installed, I can access databases in my terminal.
The sql server is running.
Im on mac os 11.1

I researched this topic, I found that a plugin can cause this, but I don't even have that plugin in my files.

```
Time Awake Since Boot: 890 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Abort trap: 6
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x6
```

Thanks in advance if you could help!

Comment: I could never make MySQL Workbench run stable on my Mac. Choose a different tool. There are more then enough on the market

Comment: I guess I'll go choose another one than.. I only wanted this because we use it in school (on windows pc-s). Thanks for the reply!

Comment: MySQL Workbench switched to Python 3, maybe that is the culprit?

Comment: I installed python 3 but still gives me the same error.

Comment: There's the same report here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65792436/mysql-workbench-quit-unexpectedly-on-mac-os-big-sur-11-1

Comment: Had the same issue, try and restart your server with  `mysql.server stop; mysql.server start`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

MySQLWorkbench 8.0.23 crashes for me on startup on macOS 11.1, but downgrading to 8.0.22 from [MySQL archives](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/) allows it to startup without a problem.

This bug is reported to the MySQL bug tracker: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102284

Comment: Same issue on macOS Catalina 10.15.7. Upvoted, downgrading to 8.0.22 works fine

Comment: ditto on what Nick said.

Comment: Omg, we use this tool at our university, it is so buggy. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: thanks a lot. I had the same problem with 10.15.7. After downgrading it worked.

Comment: The suggested 8.0.22 version crashes at startup, too :( I'll have a look for alternatives, I have no time for that...

Comment: Can confirm that 8.0.23 crashes on MacOS BigSur 11.2.2, downgraded to 8.0.22 and it works fine. https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

Comment: MySQL Workbench 8.0.24 had been released and this appears to startup correctly for me on macOS Big Sir 11.2.3

Comment: same issue with Ventura 13.2: downgrade to 8.0.23 works fine

Comment: I had issues with 8.0.32, after downgrading to 8.0.31, crashing issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 13):

I was having the exact same issue, I was able to download the older version from [MySql's archives](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/), and it worked for me.

P.S., I also had to go into <kbd>System Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Security & Privacy</kbd> > <kbd>General</kbd> and *open anyway* for MySQL.

Answer (score 7):

Faced the similar problem on my Mac, but workbench crashed every time I run the query. Solved the issue by degrading the versions.

I used 8.0.32. But after installing 8.0.31, workbench won't crash anymore.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, downgrading from `8.0.32` to `8.0.31` did the trick.

Go to the **product archives** here and you'll be able to find it.

**Link:** https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

This should solve the problem for you.

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights

Comment: @NicoHaase I added the link to the archive to download the exact version. I'll call this *new*

Comment: What **exactly** is new in that? That link was already posted three times within this question

Answer (score 1):

I was having this crash issue on my mac Monterey 12.3 with the latest Mysql workbench 8.0.31, So I uninstalled it and did a fresh install of lower version  8.0.27. And it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

As many people suggested, downloading and using the previous version may help resolve the issue. I encountered an error while using version 8.0.31, so I downloaded version 8.0.30 and to my surprise, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall current version and re download 8.0.31 version  from this link : https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/  working fine no more crash

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem (macOS BigSur 11.6.3) : could not upgrade to any v8.x version.
After further investigation, I found that I was having a user module (script I wrote several years ago to generate automatic documentation).
After removing it from the 6.3 version (menu : Scripting > Scripting shells > Files > User module) I was able to install and run MysqlWorkbench 8 (8.28 for instance)