# MySQL workbench crashes whenever I try and access a table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to learn how to use MySQL. I installed the latest version of MySQL and MySQL workbench, however every time I try and access a table I've made the app immediately just crashes. The error report makes no sense to me.

I'm using a macbook air m1 and I've double checked I have the correct versions installed.

Is this a common issue and does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

I was advised to try reinstalling MySQL, which I did and there was no improvement. I've tried restarting my machine, but I have no idea what to try other than that.

Comment: The fact that the error message means nothing to you doesn't mean that it won't to someone here. Unfortunately, we can't see your screen to read it, and you failed to add it to your post. It's really difficult to help when you keep all the relevant information to yourself. *The app just crashes* with no more information is totally useless.

Comment: Pls edit your question and add the error, as requested - you could also add whatever "*the correct versions*" are, they are also possibly relevant (and why you used the term "*correct*"?).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit late, but if you are using version 8.0.32, try downgrading to 8.0.31; My workbench would repeatedly crash on certain queries, and downgrading fixed the issue for me.

Also, see similar answers [MySQL Workbench crashes on mac os (fresh install)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798626/mysql-workbench-crashes-on-mac-os-fresh-install)